# Why does PostgreSQL cursor.execute() command add single quotes?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Simple SQL statement:

```
sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"
cursor.execute(sql, ("user_table",))
```

It fails with:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'user_table'"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'user_table'
```

The single quotes in the SQL statement are the problem.  If I run this it works just fine:

```
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_table")
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`AsIs`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs) adapter is *useful for objects whose string representation is already valid as SQL representation*

```
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (AsIs("user_table"),))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the argument-syntax only for arguments, not for table or column names.

Comment: And that makes total sense.  Thanks!

Comment: More strictly, query parameters are suitable for passing literals only. You cannot use them to substitute identifiers or keywords.